# How to create a trigger in nestjs with typeorm?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Is there any way to create a trigger in nestjs/typeorm. This trigger should

1. Auto-increment a column whenever that row is updated
2. Work even when working directly in mysql database

Comment: btw `@nestjs/typeorm` has no abstractions to that. It's just TypeORM.

Comment: I m beginner, I have no idea. So, can you help me out with this?

Comment: you can search for "typeorm trigger", I didn't write anything like that before.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know whether @nestjs/typeorm has that functionality or not but the core typeorm package do support triggers out of the box.

You can try something like this using the core typeorm package :

```js
@EventSubscriber()
export class PostSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface {
 
    /**
     * Called before entity update.
     */
    beforeUpdate(event: UpdateEvent<any>) {
        console.log(`BEFORE ENTITY UPDATED: `, event.entity)
        manager.update(YourEntity, { yourColumn : value })
    }

    /**
     * Called after entity update.
     */
    afterUpdate(event: UpdateEvent<any>) {
        console.log(`AFTER ENTITY UPDATED: `, event.entity)
    }

   
}
```

The event object contains :

- dataSource: DataSource - DataSource used in the event.
- queryRunner: QueryRunner - QueryRunner used in the event transaction.
- manager: EntityManager - EntityManager used in the event transaction.

**Note:** All database operations in the subscribed event listeners should be performed using the event object's queryRunner or manager instance.

You can further read about this at https://typeorm.io/listeners-and-subscribers#what-is-a-subscriber.

Do let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: This approach doesnt satisfy my 2nd requirement : ( @Afaq Javed

Answer (score -3):

I fixed this issue by explicitly creating triggers in mysql.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).